# Silverlight 3 Font Embedding and the Back Button Issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, fonts

I've hit an odd snag in font embedding. I've embedded the webdings.ttf font as outlined in Tim Heuer's blog article  [Embedding fonts in Silverlight 2](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/10/embedding-fonts-in-silverlight-2.aspx)

This works well but if I navigate away from the page with my Silverlight app to a non-Silverlight page (plain .aspx or html page) and then navigate back using the back button, the app no longer renders the embedded font. Refreshing the page (F5) restores the embedded font. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should try again with his updated video: http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=69800